# Background-image from sass is not rendered

Tags: css, sass, node-sass

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9oNA.png)

Following  image is my folder structure, I have tried to add the background image using node-sass and it is node getting detected even after the render message is shown, the scss related to the background-image URL is not being added to main.css anyone pls suggest a solution

**main.scss**

```
@import 'config';
*{
   box-sizing:border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: $primary-color;
  height: 100%;
  color: $secondary-color;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
// Headings
h1,
h2,
h3 {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  //This exactly means h1.lg-heading
  &.lg-heading {
    font-size: 6rem;
  }
  &.sm-heading {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    padding: 0.2rem 1rem;
    background: #D8C3A5(darken($primary-color, 2), 0.5);
  }
}

a {
  color: $secondary-color;
}
header{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    width:100% ;
}

.text-secondary{
color: $text-color;
}
main{
    padding: 4rem;
    height: 100%;

    .socials{
        margin-top: 1rem;

        a{
            padding: 0.4rem;

            &:hover{
                color:$text-color;
               @include easeOut();
            }
        }
    }
    &#home{
        overflow: hidden;
        h1{
            margin-top:20vh;
        }
    }
}
```

**config.scss**

```
$primary-color: #eae7dc;
$secondary-color: #e85a4f;
$text-color: #123C69;
$show-home-img: true;
$home_img: image-url('./img/bg.jpg');
$background-opacity: 0.9; 

@mixin background {

    @if $show-home-img {
        
        &#bg-img{
            background:$home_img no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size: cover;
            &:after{
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                right: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                z-index: -1;
                background-color: rgba($primary-color,$background-opacity);
            }
        }
    }
}


@mixin easeOut{
    transition: color 0.5s ease-out
}
```

**index.html**

```
<body id="bg-img">
    <header>
        <div class="menu-btn">
            <div class="btn-line"></div>
            <div class="btn-line"></div>
            <div class="btn-line"></div>


            <nav class="menu-branding">
                <ul class="menu-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="">Projects</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main id="home">
        <h1 class="lg-heading">
            Tanisha <span class="text-secondary">Gupta</span>
        </h1>
        <h2 class="sm-heading"> Web Developer, Designer & Curator</h2>
        <div class="socials">
            <a href="">
                <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="">
                <i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="">
                <i class="fab fa-medium fa-2x"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="">
                <i class="fab fa-github fa-2x"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src=js/main.js></script>
    <!-- FontAwesome -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c28f07619f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I can understand your issue, but I can't reproduce this issue with screenshot. kindly share your code here

Comment: We need more information. Is the bg image not loaded or is it not added to the generated CSS file? These are two completely different things. If it isn't added to SCSS, check your build process. If it is added, check your network tab in the browser to see what file is fetched.

Comment: @viira exactly that the the scss is not added to the generated css

Comment: You can add your scss code here then

Comment: @Viira Just added both the scss files, I hope this gives you a better understanding of the issue

Comment: I have added my answer

Comment: you created a mixin for your background, where do you actually use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image won't render because there's no such property as `background: image-url()` just set `url()`.
You should modify the property like this

```css
$home_img: url('https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300');

#bg-img {
  background: $home_img no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg-img" style="height: 600px; width: 600px;">
</div>
```

Codepen [link](https://codepen.io/Ev1ltw1n/pen/yLXEwMB)

**UPDATE:**

I have updated my answer, after analyzing it with your HTML I have found where the issue occurs. The background image won't appear because you have added a pseudo element for the same tag it will overlap the background image. consider removing the `background-color`

Also don't forgot to call the mixin in your `main.scss` file

Add `@include background()` in top of your `main.scss` file

```css
#bg-img{
            background:$home_img;
            background-attachment: fixed;
          z-index: 2;
            background-size: cover;
            &:after{
               // content: "";
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                right: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                z-index: -1;
                background-color: rgba($primary-color,$background-opacity);
            }
       }
```

Remove this `::after` element for the `body` tag

Updated codpen [link](https://codepen.io/Ev1ltw1n/pen/yLXEwMB?editors=1100)

Comment: changed $home_img: url('./img/bg.jpg');  to this and like what you said but it's not working, it would be great if you could provide any other approach

Comment: Add you html code too then

Comment: Added the index.html as well pls check

Comment: Yes. I have found the issue, I'll update it in my answer wait

Comment: Thank you so much for the help it worked

Comment: I tried upvoting but I just started StackOverflow so the reputation is low 

Comment: you can select the tick mark however